# Possible memory corruption MBP 2020

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, crash

I have a MacBook Pro 2020 13-inch with the 10th gen i5 CPU (about a month old).

My laptop froze, the screen turned black and the fans went 100% for a sec. After restarting, it stated that it was because of the following problem:

```
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801002b6be): 
"Possible memory corruption: pmap_pv_remove(0xffffff804f5eea80, 0x700007bc9000, 0x6c11, 0x8010000376e95066, 0xffffff9244933b14, 0xffffff9244933ad0): 
pv not on hash, head: 0xffffff806adf7080, 0x29d4355cd000, priors: 
1"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.121.2/osfmk/i386/pmap_internal.h:979
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address


BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Skype Helper (Re
```

The log continues for a bit longer, but I think the most important parts are there. For context, I had some programs opens and was Skyping.

I tried googling a bit and saw that this is an issue with some older MacBooks. They mention reseating the RAM sticks, but that is not an option with the 2020 model (of course). They mention that some part of the RAM could be corrupted.

Now my question:
Given that my MacBook is now 1 month old, should I be worried? It has not happened since, but does this point to a bigger issue? Or is this just a one-time thing or a software problem.

Comment: As your Mac is 1 month old, you are covered by AppleCare, and you can, at the very least, contact Apple directly.

Comment: That is true, but my question was a bit different, I'll try to rephrase it a little bit. Is it just a normal error message which could be caused by a plethora of causes or is this an error message which pops up at a hardware failure and thus a little bit more serious?